# How to concatenate two columns that might contain NULL values in a select statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I tried with:

```
SELECT CONCAT(col1, col2) AS NewCol FROM tableName
```

It works only if col1 and col2 are not null, else NewCol becomes null, even if one of col1 and col2 is not null. I want it to display whatever value that is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`CONCAT_WS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws).

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('', col1, col2) AS NewCol FROM tableName
```

It would return an empty string in case both the values are `null`.

Documentation:

> CONCAT_WS(separator,str1,str2,...)
>
> CONCAT_WS() stands for Concatenate With Separator and is a special form of CONCAT(). The first argument is the separator for the rest of the arguments. The separator is added between the strings to be concatenated. The separator can be a string, as can the rest of the arguments. If the separator is NULL, the result is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CONCAT_WS**. its NULL safe. the first argument is the separator.

**sample**

```
MariaDB [l]> SELECT CONCAT_WS('',NULL,'123');
+--------------------------+
| CONCAT_WS('',NULL,'123') |
+--------------------------+
| 123                      |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [l]>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
SELECT ISNULL([col1],'') + ISNULL([col2],'') AS NewCol FROM tableName
```